# Getting error : 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database'.' in SQL Server data access

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, database-connection

I have written this code:

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string connectionName="MvcwebDB")
{
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;
}

public static List<T> LoadData<T>(string sql)
{
    using(IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        return cnn.Query<T>(sql).ToList();
    }
}

public static int SaveData<T>(string sql, T data)
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        return cnn.Execute(sql, data);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error at `cnn.Execute`:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database

This is the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="MvcwebDB" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MvcwebDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Show us your **connection string** !

Comment: And include the sql query.

Comment: You should show us the SQL query that produces this error. This particular error often happens when a `USE` database statement is incorrectly formatted, but it could be other things.

Comment: This is the connection string- <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MvcwebDB" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MvcwebDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.data.sqlclient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: You should **NOT** put stuff like this (code, config) into a comment which cannot be properly formatted - it's really really hard to read and understand. Instead - **EDIT** your question (as I now did for you) and add the additional info there!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community.

This is happening because you likely have a syntax error in the connection string within your config.

It should follow something like:
`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`

Check out [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for more info.

Comment: Below is the connection string, I have added in web.config

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MvcwebDB" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MvcwebDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.data.sqlclient"/>
  </connectionStrings>